# Why does downcasting my class fail, but upcasting then downcasting succeed?

Tags: swift

I have the following classes:

```
class Shape {
    var name: String
    var area: Int?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Rectangle : Shape {
    public func calculateArea(width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.area = width * height
    }
}
```

I get a `Shape`, which I decide to treat as a `Rectangle`. My understanding is that I should downcast, like so:

```
let someShape = Shape(name: "Test shape")
let rect = someShape as! Rectangle
```

This fails. From Xcode:

> Could not cast value of type 'Shape' (0x103c76910) to 'Rectangle' (0x103c76530)

If I instead start with a `Rectangle`, upcast to a `Shape`, and downcast back to `Rectangle`, it works:

```
let rect = Rectangle(name: "Test rect")
let someShape = rect as! Shape
let downcastRect = someShape as! Rectangle
```

Why does my first downcast fail, but my second downcast succeed?

Comment: casting != converting

Comment: @vikingosegundo Good point – is there an idiomatic way to 'convert' a class instance to a subclass?

Comment: there cant be, sorry. that is left to you and depends on many variables. btw: nothing in your codes should be a class. Shape should be a protocol with structs implementing them.

Comment: @vikingosegundo thanks for the advice, will check it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance doesn't change when casting the type. The instance is the actual allocated object being held in memory. The variable is just a reference to the instance.

In the first example, the instance is a `Shape`. The variable that references the instance can't be of type `Rectangle`.

In the second example, the instance is a `Rectangle`. When it's cast to a `Shape`, the instance `someShape` references is still a `Rectangle`. That allows for `someShape` to be cast back to `Rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation – is there a proper way to convert an instance of a class to an instance of a subclass?

Comment: @ductionist No, that's impossible. You have to create a new instance of the wanted type.

Comment: @ductionist unfortunately that would require creating a new instance. This can be done by using a copy constructor. `init(shape: Shape) { … }` and `let rect = Rectangle(shape: someShape)`. **WARNING!** creating a subclass from it's super-class gets tricky. Generally, you need to come up with defaults for the subclass's properties.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple - upcasting and downcasting does not change the type of the instance, it only changes the type of the variable.

In the first case you have an instance of `Shape`, which you cannot cast to a `Rectangle` because not all shapes are rectangles.

In the second case you start with an instance of `Rectangle` which you store to a `Shape` variable. However, the instance is still a `Rectangle`. Then of course you can downcast it back to `Rectangle` because it's still a `Rectange`. If you tried to cast to a different shape, e.g. a `Triangle`, the cast would fail.

That's the whole reason why we have operators like `is` and `as?`. In the first case:

```
let someShape = Shape(name: "Test shape")
print(someShape is Rectangle) // false - this is not a Rectangle
```

and in the second case:

```
let rect = Rectangle(name: "Test rect")
let someShape = rect as! Shape
print(someShape is Rectange) // true - someShape is still a Rectangle
```

Also note that you have a warning for `rect as! Shape`. The compiler knows that every `Rectangle` is a `Shape` and you can cast safely using `rect as Shape` or directly write:

```
let someShape: Shape = rect
```